# How to prevent my app from crashing when there is no input or if input is invalid

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello I am creating a unit converter app trying to self learn on how to make android apps how can make my app show a message instead of crashing when clicking the convert button here are my codes if input is nothing or "."

Personaly I am thinking of disabling the button if there is not input in the fromEditText.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button_convert"
         android:layout_width="231dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
         android:onClick="convert"
         android:text="Convert" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
         android:text="Unit 1"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
         android:text="Unit 2"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="136dp" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner_to"
         android:layout_width="368dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="42dp"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner_from"
         android:layout_width="368dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="163dp"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText_to"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="177dp"
         android:clickable="false"
         android:cursorVisible="false"
         android:ems="10"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         android:inputType="numberDecimal"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="85dp"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="223dp" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText_from"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="numberDecimal"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="85dp"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="96dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Converter class

```
package com.appcreator.isa.theunitconverterapp;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class Converter
{
    public enum UnitsDistance
    {
        Inch,
        Centimetre,
        Foot,
        Yard,
        Metre,
        Mile,
        Kilometre,
        NauticalMile;

        private static LogRecord dlgAlert;

    // Helper method to convert text to one of the above constants
        public static UnitsDistance fromString(String text)
        {
             if (text != null)
             {
                  for (UnitsDistance UnitsDistance : UnitsDistance.values())
                  {
                      if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(UnitsDistance.toString()))
                      {
                          return UnitsDistance;
                      }
                  }
             }

             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find a value for " + text);
        }
    }

// What can I multiply by to get me from my fromUnitsDistance to my toUnitsDistance?
    private final double multiplier;
    public Converter(UnitsDistance from, UnitsDistance to)
    {
         double constant = 1;
        // Set the multiplier, else if fromUnitsDistance = toUnitsDistance, then it is 1
         switch (from)
         {
             case Inch:
                 if (to == UnitsDistance.Centimetre)
                 {
                     constant = 2.54;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Foot)
                 {
                     constant = 0.0833333;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Yard)
                 {
                     constant = 0.0277778;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Metre)
                 {
                     constant = 0.0254;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Mile)
                 {
                     constant = 1.5783e-5;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Kilometre)
                 {
                     constant = 2.54e-5;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.NauticalMile)
                 {
                     constant = 1.3715e-5;
                 }
                 break;
             case Centimetre:
                 if (to == UnitsDistance.Inch)
                 {
                     constant = 0.393701;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Foot)
                 {
                     constant = 0.0328084;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Yard)
                 {
                     constant = 0.0109361;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Metre)
                 {
                     constant = 0.01;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Mile)
                 {
                     constant = 6.2137e-6;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Kilometre)
                 {
                     constant = 1e-5;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.NauticalMile)
                 {
                     constant = 5.3996e-6;
                 }
                 break;
             case Foot:
                 if (to == UnitsDistance.Inch)
                 {
                     constant = 12;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Centimetre)
                 {
                     constant = 30.48;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Yard)
                 {
                     constant = 0.333333;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Metre)
                 {
                     constant = 0.3048;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Mile)
                 {
                     constant = 0.000189394;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Kilometre)
                 {
                     constant = 0.0003048;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.NauticalMile )
                 {
                     constant = 0.000164579;
                 }
                 break;
             case Yard:
                 if (to == UnitsDistance.Inch)
                 {
                     constant = 36;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Centimetre)
                 {
                     constant = 91.44;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Foot)
                 {
                     constant = 3;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Metre)
                 {
                     constant = 0.9144;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Mile)
                 {
                     constant = 0.000568182;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Kilometre)
                 {
                     constant = 0.0009144;
                 } else if (to == UnitsDistance.NauticalMile )
                 {
                constant = 0.000493737;
            }
            break;
        case Metre:
            if (to == UnitsDistance.Inch)
            {
                constant = 39.3701;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Centimetre)
            {
                constant = 100;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Foot)
            {
                constant = 3.28084;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Yard)
            {
                constant = 1.09361;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Mile)
            {
                constant = 0.000621371;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Kilometre)
            {
                constant = 0.001;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.NauticalMile)
            {
                constant = 0.000539957;
            }
            break;
        case Mile:
            if (to == UnitsDistance.Inch)
            {
                constant = 63360;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Centimetre)
            {
                constant = 160934;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Foot)
            {
                constant = 5280;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Yard)
            {
                constant = 1760;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Metre)
            {
                constant = 1609.34;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Kilometre)
            {
                constant = 1.60934;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.NauticalMile)
            {
                constant = 1.1508;
            }
            break;
        case Kilometre:
            if (to == UnitsDistance.Inch)
            {
                constant = 39370.1;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Centimetre)
            {
                constant = 100000;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Foot)
            {
                constant = 3280.84;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Yard)
            {
                constant = 1093.61;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Metre)
            {
                constant = 1000;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Mile)
            {
                constant = 0.621371;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.NauticalMile)
            {
                constant = 0.539957;
            }
            break;
        case NauticalMile:
            if (to == UnitsDistance.Inch)
            {
                constant = 72913.4;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Centimetre)
            {
                constant = 185200;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Foot)
            {
                constant = 6076.12;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Yard)
            {
                constant = 2025.37;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Metre)
            {
                constant = 1852;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Mile)
            {
                constant = 1.15078;
            } else if (to == UnitsDistance.Kilometre)
            {
                constant = 1.852;
            }
            break;
    }

    multiplier = constant;
  }

  // Convert the UnitsDistance!
  public double convert(double input)
 {
    return input * multiplier;
 }

  }
```

Java Main Activity class

```
package com.appcreator.isa.theunitconverterapp;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextUtils;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.unitsdistance, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner from = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
    Spinner to = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_to);

    from.setAdapter(adapter);
    to.setAdapter(adapter);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public void convert(View view)
{
    Spinner fromSpinner, toSpinner;
    final EditText fromEditText, toEditText;

    fromSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
    toSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_to);
    fromEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_from);
    toEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_to);

    // Get the string from the Spinners and number from the EditText
    String fromString = (String) fromSpinner.getSelectedItem();
    String toString = (String) toSpinner.getSelectedItem();
    double input = Double.valueOf(fromEditText.getText().toString());

    Button check =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_convert);




    // Convert the strings to something in our Unit enu,
    Converter.UnitsDistance fromUnit = Converter.UnitsDistance.fromString(fromString);
    Converter.UnitsDistance toUnit = Converter.UnitsDistance.fromString(toString);

    // Create a converter object and convert!
    Converter converter = new Converter(fromUnit, toUnit);

    double result = converter.convert(input);

    check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (fromEditText.getText().toString().length() == 0 || fromEditText.getText().toString() == ".")
            {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Input is invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
      });

     toEditText.setText(String.valueOf(result));
   }
  }
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">The Unit Converter App</string>
<string-array name="unitsdistance">
    <item>Inch</item>
    <item>Centimetre</item>
    <item>Foot</item>
    <item>Yard</item>
    <item>Metre</item>
    <item>Mile</item>
    <item>Kilometre</item>
    <item>NauticalMile</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Problem everytime I click a button the app stops if there is nothing fromEditText or if it only have "." in it without numbers obviously.

UPDATED Main Activity

```
    package com.appcreator.isa.theunitconverterapp;



    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
   {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.unitsdistance, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner from = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
    Spinner to = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_to);

    from.setAdapter(adapter);
    to.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public void convert(View view)
{




    Button check =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_convert);




    check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Spinner fromSpinner, toSpinner;
            EditText  toEditText;
            toEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_to);
            EditText fromEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_from);;


            fromSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
            toSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_to);
            String fromString = (String) fromSpinner.getSelectedItem();
            String toString = (String) toSpinner.getSelectedItem();

            Converter.UnitsDistance fromUnit = Converter.UnitsDistance.fromString(fromString);
            Converter.UnitsDistance toUnit = Converter.UnitsDistance.fromString(toString);

            Converter converter = new Converter(fromUnit, toUnit);


            String str = fromEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            boolean valid = true;
            double val = 0;

            try {
                val = Double.parseDouble(str);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                valid = false;
            }

            if( valid )
            {
                // use the number
                if (fromEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 )
                {
                    double input = Double.valueOf(fromEditText.getText().toString().trim());
                    double result = converter.convert(input);
                    toEditText.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                }

            }
            else
                {
                // handle invalid entry
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Input is invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });


     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether a valid number has been entered, you can parse the number and catch `NumberFormatException` to detect if it is valid. For example:

```
String str = fromEditText.getText().toString().trim();
boolean valid = true;
double val = 0;

try {
    val = Double.parseDouble(str);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    valid = false;
}

if( valid ) {
    // use the number
}
else {
    // handle invalid entry
}
```

There are more non-parsable combinations than just blank and ".". For example "........" or any number of combination of spaces, periods, and commas a user could for some reason decide to enter.

Comment: Actually testing on my phone the user can't post more than one "." and can't use periods or commas or spaces however it used to be able to keep it empty